# Testing: how to deal with a private variable in a class to test?

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I'm new to Unit Testing. Simple question about private variables.

I have a `UIViewController` with

```
private var tableView:UITableView
```

I can't access the `tableView` variable to check the number of rows (to see if the data are loaded correctly).

The best solution I could think of so far is to add a method `getRows()` to the original implementation of the class.

```
  func getRows() -> Int {  return tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) }
```

Subclassing the class is not a solution, because `tableView` is private.

Am I correct?

Comment: If you want to test data are loaded correctly why not just test the data only?

Comment: @WilliamHu mhm. I thought it was a good idea to test if the data is displayed on screen. Isn't?